# How do I loop until I get the right answer?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to program something that repeats itself until it gets the amount right. My program is basically a loan program that helps you figure out how long it'll take for you to pay off a loan with interest. So far, I managed to get the first month to print out (although not exactly right...), but I need it to keep repeating until the loan amount has been paid off. I hope that makes sense.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project4{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Project4.out");

        double lamnt;
        double mpay;
        double intrestrate;
        double mnthintrest;
        double mintrestrate;

        System.out.print("Enter the Loan Amount: ");
        lamnt = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();;

        System.out.print("Enter the intrest rate (Ex:5.75): ");
        intrestrate = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the monthly payment you want to make: ");          
        mpay = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        mintrestrate = intrestrate/12;
        mnthintrest = lamnt*mintrestrate; 

        System.out.println("The first month intrest rate is:" + pay);           
     }          
 }
```

I was suggested using a while loop but I'm not too sure how to make the while loop keep going until the loan amount is paid off. Also yes I know the outcome isn't right, I'm working on that part. I'm not too sure how to space out the titles properly. 
I need the output to look like this: (using 1000 in loan payment, 7.2 in interest rate, 25 for monthly pay)

Amount loan after payment #1 is: 981.00     Principle is: 19.00     Interest is: 6.00

Amount loan after payment #2 is: 961.89     Principle is: 19.11     Interest is: 5.89

Comment: Use do...while or while. You can check on the internet. How to use it

Comment: When a person pays off a loan in monthly installments, after each installment the amount remaining to be paid off decreases. Once the amount remaining reaches zero, the loan is paid off in full. Hence you need to keep track of the remaining amount and your `while` loop condition needs to be something like: `while (remainingAmount > 0)`

Comment: You only need one scanner for `System.in`

Comment: To make it easier to read and debug, Java programs usually follow some coding conventions. Variables and method names are in snakeCase, and classes use CamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to use a while loop until your loan is paid off, just do something like:

```
while (lamnt > 0) {
    // Do stuff to pay off the loan here.
}
```

As long as you're updating the lamnt within the loop, that should work.

Hope that helped!
;)

Edit: Also, make sure you're only creating scanners that you actually use.  And don't forget to close them at the end of the scope!

Comment: Never close a `System.in` scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that interest rate would be entered in percentage, the `mnthintrest` calculation would need an additional multiplication by 1/100 i.e. 0.01

```
mnthintrest = lamnt*mintrestrate*(0.01);
```

You also need to edit the variable pay to mpay

```
System.out.println("The first month intrest rate is:" + pay);
```

I think your logic for money paid per month should be ( as others suggested) - reducing the loan amount until it reaches zero.

Now coming to implementation, you will be reducing the amount and since we wouldn't want the original data ( variable) to be affected, we could first store it an temporary variable.
For keeping track of #number of payment, we can keep the month count in another variable.

You could think of something like this:

```
double temp = lamnt;   
int monthNumber = 1;

while(temp>0){

    mnthintrest = temp*mintrestrate*0.01;
    double principlePaidPerMonth= mpay- mnthintrest;

    temp = temp - principlePaidPerMonth; // reducing the principle amount paid before printing         
    System.out.println("\nAmount left after payment "+monthNumber+" is:" + temp);
    System.out.println("This month intrest is:" + mnthintrest);
    System.out.println("Principle paid is:" + principlePaidPerMonth);


    monthNumber++;

}   

// text to be printed could be different
```

It is a good practice to keep variable names as meaningful as possible and to declare the variables as much closer to their first use.
So you could declare the variables for interest and interest rate just at the time of initializing above where the while loop part starts.

```
double mintrestrate = intrestrate/12;
double mnthintrest = lamnt*mintrestrate;
```

For formatting, you could use `System.out.printf()` instead of `println` - this could help format the number of digits shown after decimal

For getting precision - you could use absolute/ceiling functions available in Math class.

Comment: I tried something like this it gave an initialized error. It says mintrestrate wasn't intialized. Was it a placement error maybe? or do I need to make 'double static' instead? Also that 25 is supposed to be user friendly. Like it's not always going to be 25. When the program asks the payment they could put in 5 or 10. So I want to avoid hard coding it.

Comment: You don't need to make it static - could be a placement error. You could even declare mintrestrate  at the time of initializing. And  of course, that snippet is for an example. Replace 25 with mpay.  I will edit the post for that

Comment: I also just edited the place where you are showing the amount left i.e. temp = temp - principlePaidPerMonth;  - it would need to be deducted before printing it on console.